# Managed property is not being set, coming from a User Profile custom property

Tags: 2013, search, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, managed-property

I have a custom user profile property that is mapped to 2 different managed properties. For some reason, it is only appearing in 1 one of the managed properties. I can confirm the managed properties are identical except for the different crawled properties to which they are mapped (the managed property that works only maps to this one custom user profile property, while the other managed property also maps to several properties).

I have run a full crawl a few times against the People content source to no avail. Do I need to run a full crawl against *all* the content sources used by the managed property, even if the missing crawled property is in the People content source? Is there anything else I can do short of rebuilding the UPS?

Comment: Did you define the Property at the SSA (farm) or Site Collection (or Site)?

Comment: The property was defined in the SSA

Comment: On the one with "several mapped props" do you have it set to "the first" or "All"?

Comment: It is set to "All".

Comment: Are you certain the other properties are not interfering.

Comment: Update: apparently there was a content enrichment service I was unaware of that was interfering. :(